struct filename, difference between fields `name` and `uptr`
I'm working on a Linux kernel (v5.15) module and I need to create a wrapper for the _do_filp_open to checks the file path opened. I'm using the kprobe mechanism to intercept the call and to define a wrapper:
static struct kprobe kp = {
    .symbol_name = "_do_filp_open",
    .pre_handler = sys_open_wrapper,
};

static int init_function(void) {
    int ret;
    printk("%s: initializing\n",MODNAME);
    ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
    ...

And I correctly get the pre-execution of my wrapper. Here, I'm retrieving the full path of a file and I found the struct filename structure as parameter of my function; its definition is the following, according to documentation:
struct filename {
    const char      *name;  /* pointer to actual string */
    const __user char   *uptr;  /* original userland pointer */
    int         refcnt;
    struct audit_names  *aname;
    const char      iname[];
};

But now I don't understand correctly the difference between name and uptr fields and how correctly use them. From documentation, I can understand that uptr points to an user space virtual address, while name is probably pointing to a kernel space address. What I can't understand is:

the content of the two pointers is the same. why do I need both of them??
they can keep either the relative path or absolute path of the file that is going to be open. Which one should I use to retrieve the full path when they keep the relative path??

About the second point, i tried this, also found in the web:
int get_user_full_path(const char __user *filename, ssize_t len, char *output_buffer){
    struct path path;
    int dfd=AT_FDCWD;
    char *ret_ptr=NULL;
    int error = -EINVAL,flag=0;
    unsigned int lookup_flags = 0;
    char *tpath=kmalloc(1024,GFP_KERNEL);
    if ((flag & ~(AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW | AT_NO_AUTOMOUNT)) != 0)
    {
        kfree(tpath);
        return error;
    }
    if (!(flag & AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW))
        lookup_flags |= LOOKUP_FOLLOW;

    error = user_path_at(dfd, filename, lookup_flags, &path);
    if (error)
    {
        kfree(tpath);
        return error;
    }
    ret_ptr = d_path(&path, tpath, 1024);
    sprintf(output_buffer, ret_ptr, strlen(ret_ptr));
    kfree(tpath);
    return 0;
}

But this only works with the uptr field, i.e. the user space pointer: I tried to change the signature to int get_user_full_path(const char *filename, ssize_t len, char *output_buffer), and tried to use the name field, but the user_path_at is failing as we all can guess.
I don't know if it's correctly to use the user pointer and which problems may occur, then I'm here. Can anyone help me??
Sorry if question has several points, but I really can't understand how does this structure work and how to use it properly.
Thanks in advance.
